# kubectl keeps asking for login every command

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, microk8s

What happened:
We're on AKS with RBAC enabled. Executing any kubectl/helm command that connects to the k8s cluster, I have to reauthenticate. Output:

`To sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code XXXX to authenticate.`
This succeeds but then when I execute the next kubectl command I have to reauthenticate again.

What you expected to happen:
Authenticate and use that token for more than one command.

How to reproduce it (as minimally and precisely as possible):

Get credentials and then execute any kubectl command.

Anything else we need to know?:

Environment:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.0", GitCommit:"e199641833566e5d052d1f1fa930c4d7575bd50", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-08-26T14:30:33Z", GoVersion:"go1.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

On one of the git answer (https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/1057), I found that we have to remove config.lock to resolve the issue, but there is no such file in my case.
Help appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using [`az login`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/authenticate-azure-cli) An auth token is cached locally on your environment and should give you access to your Kubernetes cluster.

Then follow the Microsoft [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-walkthrough#connect-to-the-cluster) to install `kubectl`.

```
az aks install-cli
az aks get-credentials --resource-group myResourceGroup --name myAKSCluster
```